# Configure OneToOne mapping with non-key column in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I would like to create a OneToOne mapping between two of my entities, using non-primary columns. How do I configure this in NHibernate ?

Entities:

```cs
public class DocumentLock
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string LockedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual string DocumentCode { get; set; }
    public virtual LegalDocument LegalDocument { get; set; }
}
public class LegalDocument
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string DocumentCode { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentLock DocumentLock { get; set; }
}
```

Note: `DocumentCode` is a string generated in the application, it's unique for each `DocumentLock` and `LegalDocument`

Mappings:

```cs
public class DocumentLockMap : ClassMapping<DocumentLock>
{
    public DocumentLockMap()
    {
        ManyToOne(x => x.LegalDocument, map =>
        {
            map.Column("DocumentCode");
            map.Insert(false);
            map.Update(false);
            map.Unique(true);
            map.Cascade(Cascade.None);
        });
    }
}
public class LegalDocumentMap : ClassMapping<LegalDocument>
{
    public LegalDocumentMap()
    {
        OneToOne(x => x.DocumentLock, map =>
        {
            map.PropertyReference(x => x.LegalDocument);
            map.Cascade(Cascade.All.Include(Cascade.DeleteOrphans));
            map.Fetch(FetchKind.Join);
            map.Constrained(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Query code:

```cs
using (var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var data = session.QueryOver<LegalDocument>().List();
};
```

Generated query:

```sql
SELECT
    this_.Id as id1_1_1_,
    this_.Title as title2_1_1_,
    this_.DocumentCode as documentcode3_1_1_,
    documentlo2_.Id as id1_0_0_,
    documentlo2_.LockedBy as lockedby2_0_0_,
    documentlo2_.DocumentCode as documentcode3_0_0_ 
FROM
    LegalDocument this_ 
inner join
    DocumentLock documentlo2_ 
        on this_.Id = documentlo2_.DocumentCode
```

My expectation for the generated query is: it should join using `this_.DocumentCode`, not `this_.Id`

```
on this_.DocumentCode = documentlo2_.DocumentCode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Firo and @Roman Artiukhin.

Solution: use `ManyToMany` on both mappings
So in my case, I'll use:

```
public class DocumentLockMap : ClassMapping<DocumentLock>
{
    public DocumentLockMap()
    {
        ManyToOne(x => x.LegalDocument, map =>
        {
            map.PropertyRef("DocumentCode");
            map.Column("DocumentCode");
            map.Insert(false);
            map.Update(false);
            map.Unique(true);
            map.Cascade(Cascade.None);
        });
    }
}


public class LegalDocumentMap : ClassMapping<LegalDocument>
{
    public LegalDocumentMap()
    {
        ManyToOne(x => x.DocumentLock, map =>
        {
            map.PropertyRef("DocumentCode");
            map.Column("DocumentCode");
            map.Insert(false);
            map.Update(false);
            map.Unique(true);
            map.Cascade(Cascade.All.Include(Cascade.DeleteOrphans));
            map.Fetch(FetchKind.Join);
        });
    }
}
```

Generated query:

```
SELECT
    this_.Id as id1_1_1_,
    this_.Title as title2_1_1_,
    this_.DocumentCode as documentcode3_1_1_,
    documentlo2_.Id as id1_0_0_,
    documentlo2_.LockedBy as lockedby2_0_0_,
    documentlo2_.DocumentCode as documentcode3_0_0_ 
FROM
    LegalDocument this_ 
left outer join
    DocumentLock documentlo2_ 
        on this_.DocumentCode = documentlo2_.DocumentCode
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DocumentLockMap : ClassMapping<DocumentLock>
{
    public DocumentLockMap()
    {
        ManyToOne(x => x.LegalDocument, map =>
        {
            map.PropertyRef("DocumentCode"); <-- needed
            map.Column("DocumentCode");
            map.Insert(false);
            map.Update(false);
            map.Unique(true);
            map.Cascade(Cascade.None);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution but it still generates `this_.Id = documentlo2_.DocumentCode`

Comment: Solution is to use `ManyToOne` instead of  `OneToOne`. It's not only about `<-- needed` comment

Comment: @RomanArtiukhin thanks, I tried changing both mappings into `ManyToMany`, and it works. I'll post my solution.

Comment: @NamLe you are right, i forgot to post the other side and didn't have time to check here. should be `ManyToOne` on both sides instead of `ManyToMany`